# setadapter for android not working. empty adapter or listview?

Tags: android

im just trying to create a listview using a simple adapter. the setadapter is not working. this is my code. my setcontentview is before this block of code and this is in oncreate.

```
        ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
map.put("CType", "Alarm");
map.put("RType", "Once");
map.put("hour", "1");
map.put("minute", "1");
map.put("second", "30");
arraylist.add(map);
String[] stringarray= new String[] {"CType", "RType", "hour","minute","second"};
int[] intarray = new int[] {R.id.clocktextviewalarmtimer,R.id.clocktextviewrepeatonce,
        R.id.clocktextviewhours,R.id.clocktextviewminutes,R.id.clocktextviewseconds};
ListView clocklistview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.clocklistview);
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this,arraylist,R.layout.list_clock,stringarray,intarray);

clocklistview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

this is the xml that contains my listview

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <ListView 
    android:id="@+id/clocklistview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</ListView></LinearLayout>
```

this is for my list_clock.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"


    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="3">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/clocktextviewalarmtimer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/clocktextviewrepeatonce"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/clocktextviewhours"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/clocktextviewminutes"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/clocktextviewseconds"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: have you tried this sample: http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2010/01/03/android-simple-listview-using-simpleadapter/ ? also, if you have problems with the built in adapters , it's really not hard to use the baseAdapter instead.

Comment: Why do you believe that setAdapter is not working? Is it because you don't see anything on screen? Can you show us the XML layout with your ListView in it? Is your ListView height set to match_parent?

Comment: What do you mean by "the set adapter isn't working" as I tried your code and it's working fine -- other than nothing gets displayed. :)

Comment: well, i have identified the problem and it turns out my listview is returning null for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of a custom adapter.  Try this ...

```
public class ClockListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> _arrayList;

    ClockListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList) {
        this._arrayList = arrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return (_arrayList != null) ? _arrayList.size() : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return (_arrayList != null) ? _arrayList.get(position) : null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return (_arrayList != null) ? _arrayList.indexOf(_arrayList.get(position)) : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            // REPLACE WITH YOUR LAYOUT FILE vvvvvvvvvv
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder._textView.setText("set some text here");
        return convertView;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        // ADD YOUR VIEW(S) vvvvvvvvv
        TextView _textView;

        ViewHolder(View v) {
            // REPLACE WITH YOUR TEXT vvvvvvvvv
            _textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        }
    }
}
```